# Filter for same column with multiple values using AND condition Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

The sql query is shown below.

SELECT * FROM catalogue_productcategory WHERE (category_id=40) and (product_id=7)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found the solution.
pc = ProductCategory.objects.filter(Q(category_id = 40) and Q(category_id = 44))

Answer (score 0):

Did you define model class for them?

```
class catalogue_productcategory(model.Model):
    #define your desire fields
    category = model.ForeignKey(Category)
    product = model.ForeignKey(Product)


catalogue_productcategory.objects.filter(category__id=40, product__id=7)
```